# IIS 10.0 HTTP Error 403.0 - Forbidden

Tags: iis

Windows 10, IIS 10.0, localhost, requesting my .aspx file. I keep receiving following error:

```
HTTP Error 403.0 - Forbidden.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
Most likely causes:
This is a generic 403 error and means the authenticated user is not authorized to view the page.
```

"Logon Method" and "Logon User" are "Anonymous".
Application pool has Identity: "ApplicationPoolIdentity", is running in integrated mode.
Any possible fixes?

Comment: What is the directory of your website (C:\...)? Make sure the application pool can read & execute that directory.

Comment: Say it is C:\MySite. Yes, IIS_USRS has Read & Execute permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error came from database. In such cryptic way the fact, that user X cannot connect to Y, was expressed.